# datatables ajax reload not updating parameters passed

Tags: jquery, datatables

Using `ajax.relaod` isn't updating the value that is being passed to the controller.
The variables have the correct values each time when entering the function but I'm not sure how to get reload to also see/accept the updated variables.
Do I need to destroy and rebuild the table each time?

```
if (!$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('.workorder-table')) {
    $('.workorder-table').DataTable({
        "initComplete": function () {
            hidePleaseWait();
        },
        rowCallback: function (row, data, index) {
            --row classes added here based on data
        },
        columns: [
            { "data": "Facility", "name": "Facility", "title": "Facility" },
            { "data": "ShortDescription", "name": "ShortDescription", "title": "Short Description" },
            { "data": "Created", "name": "Created", "title": "Created" },
            { "data": "Completed", "name": "Completed", "title": "Completed" },
            { "data": "Status", "name": "Status", "title": "Status" }
        ],
        ajax: {
            url: "/Facility/WorkOrderSearch",
            type: "POST",
            data: { status: $('#Status').val(), facilityID: $('#FacilityID').val(), quickView: $('#QuickView').val() }
        },
        -- options here
    });
} else {
    $('.workorder-table').DataTable().ajax.reload(hidePleaseWait);
}
```

Comment: `data` should be a function, i.e `data: function(d) { d.status: $('#Status').val() ,... }` then it will be executed upon `ajax.reload()`

Comment: Perfect thank you. If you can turn it into an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `data` is turned into a function that can be executed

```js
data: function(data) {
  data.status = $('#Status').val();
  data.facilityID = $('#FacilityID').val();
  data.quickView = $('#QuickView').val();
}
```

Then this function will be executed upon each request, i.e when `ajax.reload()` is called.

Comment: Still applicable 7/27/18 - lifesaver! Is this a "datatables" thing, or a javascript in general thing? (making it a function to execute it each reload)

Comment: @SourceMatters, it is a DataTables enhancement of jQuery AJAX, I believe the code is found here, around line 3871 -> **https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js#L3871** if `data` is a function the function is executed. jQuery AJAX does not support this (perhaps in a later version, but none I know of)